# SessionHook for SimpleSAMLphp?

Tags: php, session, simplesamlphp

I am wondering if there is a feature that mimics the [SessionHook](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPRelyingPartySettings) feature of Shibboleth that I can use in SimpleSAMLphp? I need to access a page before the ultimate redirect to the requested page is made.

Answer (score 0):

I see 3 options for you. Which one to pick likely depends on what your page is trying to accomplish.

1. [Create an AuthProc filter](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-authproc). AuthProc filters allow you to perform post authentication processing. You can create one that will send the user to the page you want. When the page is done processing it can resume the regular processing and the user will end up on the expected, requested page.
2. [Define a ReturnCallback](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-sp-api#section_4_1). If you want to just run a code snippet then you can define a callback.
3. [Define a session callback](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/development/simplesamlphp-advancedfeatures#section_8). If you want to run some code each time the session is created or loaded.